# MS Access Form: Turn Allow Edit to No and then apply filter using combo box

Tags: ms-access, vba

Can anyone help me in Ms Access Split Form?

I have three fields Country,Product, and Year in Table Cap. I have added Combobox in form for these field . I want that if one combo box value is selected it should display related record below without allowing to edit record. ....

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple ways to do this, but I'd say the best way is to display the results in a Continuous Form.  Then set the Enabled value of all the controls on the form to False.  If there ever becomes a circumstance where you want users to be allowed to edit the data, you can just flip them on and off based on an If/Then/Else statement.

Without knowing more about your dataset, that's about as much as I can tell you.

Comment: thank you, now i turn my split form into form and a subform and added a button for search , add record, and edit. For search and add i am able to write vba code, can you help me with Edit. How can i write if then else to allow edit keeping form allow edit property to false. Thank you .

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure how to allow it at a Form level.  I'd just set each individual control to Enabled/Disabled, depending on what you want to do.  If you want to prevent editing, set them to Disabled.  So, for instance if you have a text box called txtProduct you would put something in the OnLoad event like txtProduct.Enabled = False

Comment: i found the solution and it work for me. There are two solutions either do it by Master and Child relation in form and subform or either do it by VBA Code.Thank you.